# Erro com ponteiros Near e Far em código C

Tags: c, ponteiro, compilação

Erro na compilação do código em C, com ponteiros Near e Far

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {

    char *titulo_near = "Bíblia do Programador C/C++, do Jamsa!";
    char far *titulo_far = "Bíblia do Programador C/C++, do Jamsa!";

    printf("Título do livro: %Ns\n", titulo_near);
    printf("Título do livro: %Fs\n", titulo_far);

}
```

Resultado após tentar compilar no compilador GCC

[image: erros do código]

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Joga fora este livro. Ele fala de um C fora do padrão para uma arquitetura que não se usa mais, além de conter diversos erros, nem perca tempo com isto. Adote um livro moderno e correto.

Comment: Eu tenho 2 livros aqui, esse da bíblia e o outro da 6 edição da deitel em C, mas eu não gostei desse do C da deitel, eu também não gostei muito desse da bíblia, mas entre os 2 eu achei o bíblia melhor no começo. Tem algum pra recomendar ?

Comment: Não gosto de nenhum mas do Deitel é útil, este é inútil e lesivo.

Comment: Infelizmente o GCC ainda é usado em cursos de Ciência da Computação... Mas nunca deixe o colégio ou a faculdade atrapalharem a sua educação.

Comment: @Renan qual o problema do GCC?

Comment: @Maniero ops, problema de interpretação meu! Eu pensava que a crítica sobre o livro se estendia ao compilador também. Eu não programo nem sou tão fluente em C e acabei por falar mal de algo que quase não entendo. Peço desculpas.

Comment: O livro se baseia em compiladores dos anos 80.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
O livro Programação em C/C++ "A Bíblia" é, na minha opinião, um excelente livro mas, por ser um livro "velho (1999, assim como o livro C Completo e total)", usa muitos recursos que estão ultrapassados, seja pelas modificações nas tecnologias dos hardware ou nas atualizações da linguagem de programação C/C++, recomendo a leitura do mesmo apos você ter um conhecimento inicial da linguagem, bem como, sempre que achar algo estranho e/ou algum comando que não funcione adequadamente, fazer uma buscar na net ou passar no stackoverflow, mais o livro contem uma didática muito boa e já foi considerado um dos melhores sobre o assunto.

### Segue a baixo uma explicação retirada da net:

Antigamente, os processadores x86 suportavam somente um modo de operação, chamado de modo real. No modo real a memória era dividida em segmentos, com tamanho fixo de 64Kb. A programação era um grande desafio. O barramento de endereço era capaz de transportar somente 20 bits por vez, então existia um limite de endereçamento de memória de 1MB (2^20). Essa memória de 1MB era dividida em 16 segmentos de 64 Kb cada. Um segmento era dividido em deslocamentos (Offset).

A memória era endereçada em duas partes: Segmento:Offset. Então, para acessar determinada região, primeiro colocávamos o endereço do Segmento e em seguida, uma posição dentro do segmento, que é o Offset.

Ex: 0007:7B90

Bom, expliquei muito, mas até agora não falei nada dos ponteiros NEAR e FAR... mas essa explicação era necessária antes :).

Um ponteiro NEAR ocupava 2 bytes e podia acessar posições somente dentro de um segmento (64Kb). De fato, um ponteiro NEAR armazenava o Offset.

Um ponteiro FAR ocupava 4 bytes e era usado para acessar um Offset em qualquer segmento. 2 bytes eram usados para endereçar o segmento e os outros dois eram usados para o Offset.

Os ponteiros HUGE são muito parecidos com ponteiros FAR, mas têm algumas vantagens. Em comparações lógicas por exemplo, o segmento e o Offset são comparados, enquanto que somente os Offsets são comparados no caso dos ponteiros FAR. A desvantagem é que o endereçamento com um ponteiro HUGE é um pouco mais lento.

O uso de cada ponteiro dependia do modelo de memória utilizado (SMALL, TINY, LARGE, MEDIUM, etc.). O modelo de memória especificava como o segmento de código e o segmento de dados eram estruturados.

A declaração desses ponteiros (NEAR, FAR e HUGE) não fazem parte do padrão ANSI C e não são portáveis (são dependentes da plataforma x86).

A memória segmentada é coisa do passado; rodando no modo protegido, temos hoje toda a memória disponível, em um modelo conhecido como flat-memory. Não é mais necessário a distinção entre ponteiros NEAR, FAR e HUGE. Como a memória não está mais segmentada, basta um ponteiro (que no caso, é um NEAR) para acessar qualquer posição (em raros casos um ponteiro FAR ainda é necessário... para acessar o frame buffer por exemplo). Hoje, CS, DS, SS apontam para o mesmo 'segmento'.

---

Espero ter ajudado, também sou aprendiz de C/C++/C#, tenho esse livro desdo do ano 2000 e gosto muito dele.

Abraços e boa sorte na jornada!